# Universal unprovable statements that are "true": proof

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have a couple of questions regardings the following point. I've read more than once that "if the Goldbach conjecture turns out to be unprovable from $PA$, then it must be true". Now: let $\varphi$ be the statement $\forall x\psi(x)$ with $\psi$ a $\Delta_1$ formula, and suppose that in $ZF$ we can prove that $\exists m\in\omega(\neg\psi(m))$.

1. Is the following a correct way to prove that then $PA\vdash\neg\varphi$?

Taken $M\models PA$, we know that $n\mapsto n^M=(succ^M)^{(n)}(0^M)$ is an embedding of $\langle \mathbb N,+,\cdot,succ,0\rangle$ in $M$. So, in $M$, it must be true that $\neg\psi(m^M)$, that's $PA\vdash\neg\varphi$.

2. What's the role of the $\Delta_1$ hypothesis on $\psi$? One can often read "a hypothetical counterexample of $\varphi$ just requires checking finitely many numbers..."; is it this the point? Anyway, if the previous question has a positive answer, then I can't see where am I using it.
3. Bonus question: how much can I weaken the metatheory in which the implication $\neg\varphi\Rightarrow PA\vdash\neg\varphi$ holds by ensuring that it continues to be valid? For example, it is also valid in $PA$ itself (it would be: $PA\vdash[\neg\varphi\Rightarrow PA\vdash\neg\varphi]$)?

Comment: For your second question, embeddings may not necessarily preserve all formulas, but they at least preserve $\Delta_1$ formulas.

Comment: "unprovable" is not the correct word to describe the situation , "undecidable" would be better (nor provable neither (and crucial) disprovable). If the Goldbach-conjecture is false, it is also unprovable , assuming PA is consistent.

Comment: If ZFC could show that PA is independent of Goldbach's conjecture (G) (That menas PA and G is consistent and also PA and not G , assuming PA is consistent) , then we can conclude that it must be true, since in the case it is false, PA can prove this. Of course, this independence cannot be proven within PA because then PA would have proven G.

Comment: See the post [Show that Goldbach’s Conjecture is true if and only if $\mathsf {RA} ⊬ ¬ \text {Goldbach}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452879/show-that-goldbach-s-conjecture-is-true-if-and-only-if-n-not-vdash-neg-goldba)

Comment: @Peter You're right for the terminology, sorry for that. For what concerns your second comment: ok, but my (third) question was if PA+$\neg$G is able to prove the provability of $\neg$G from PA, not if PA can show that G is independent from PA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: $(1)$, we need a correctness assumption on $\mathsf{ZF}$ as well: if $\mathsf{ZF}$ is inconsistent then of course it proves the relevant sentence regardless of what's going on in $\mathbb{N}$. That said, that assumption - plus the further analysis needed for $(2)$ (see below) - will indeed give a proof as you describe.

---

Re: $(2)$, the issue is when you analyze what $M$ thinks by embedding $\mathbb{N}$ into it.

$\Sigma_1$ properties are **upwards absolute**: if $\gamma$ is $\Sigma_1$, then for each $M\models\mathsf{PA}$ we have $$\mathbb{N}\models\gamma\quad\implies\quad M\models\gamma.$$ But the complexity hypothesis can't be removed. For example, by combining the incompleteness and completeness theorems (hehehe) we get that there is a $\Pi_1$ sentence $\eta$ (intuitively: "$\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent") such that $\mathbb{N}\models\eta$ but there is some $M\models\mathsf{PA}+\neg\eta$. That is, the $\Pi_1$ fact does **not** lift from $\mathbb{N}$ to $M$, even though $\mathbb{N}$ lives inside $M$.

Proving the upwards absoluteness of $\Sigma_1$ sentences is a good exercise. For a hint:

- First, reduce it to upwards absoluteness for $\Delta_0$ sentences: if $\psi(x)$ is $\Delta_0$ and $\mathbb{N}\models\exists x\psi(x)$, fix a witness $n$ and consider the $\Delta_0$ sentence $\psi(\underline{n})$.
- Now any specific $\Delta_0$ sentence can be rewritten as a quantifier-free sentence (just replace bounded quantifiers with appropriate conjunctions/disjunctions), and show that quantifier-free sentences are preserved by homomorphisms (this actually isn't true of arbitrary structures, but does hold for models of $\mathsf{PA}$ - why is that?).

---

Re: $(3)$, yes, we can go very weak indeed. Specifically, the weak theory $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ - $\mathsf{PA}$ with the induction scheme restricted to $\Sigma_1$ formulas - proves the following:

> Every $\Pi_1$ theorem of a consistent theory is true.

(I'm hedging a bit here about how we interpret "$\Pi_1$" in the context of theories not in the language of arithmetic, like $\mathsf{ZF}$, but ignore that for now.)

And even $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ is huge overkill; if memory serves we can go as far down as $\mathsf{EFA}$. But here I'm not familiar with the details, so I'll quit while I'm ahead.